# How to actually execute a command?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm playing around making a POC and I've created the following call.

```
public string DoStuff()
{
  try
  {
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
      SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server...");
      string command = "insert into Records values (...)";
      adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    return exception.Message + " " + exception.InnerException;
  }
  return "WeeHee!";
}
```

The text I'm seeing returned is the happy one, so I conclude there's no exceptions. Hence, I conclude that the call to the DB is performed as supposed to. However, there's no new lines in the DB being created.

I'm using the same connection string as I have in my config file and the command in pasted in from SQL Manager, where it works.

So my suspicion was that although I create an insert command, I never actually execute it but according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that's how it's supposed to work.

What stupid thing do I miss here?

Comment: adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); ?

Comment: @Valentin Aha! I tried intellisensing for *execute* but I did so on the adapter only. Donkey me! Post that as  reply so I can accept as an answer, please.

Comment: connection.Open() maybe.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Thanks. It seems you are missing connection.Open also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing     `connection.Open();` and `adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server...");
  connection.Open();
  string command = "insert into Records values (...)";
  adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
  adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) instead. Using an `SqlDataAdapter` for an `INSERT` query does not make sense.

Also you should `Open` your connection *just* before you execute it.

Comment: True remark. But as I said: "*playing around making a POC*". That's not it's going to be used in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

The example you linked to returned a `SQLAdapter` for later use.

You don't need one at all:

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server..."))
 {
     string command = "insert into Records values (...)";
     connection.Open();
     var command = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Note that there are other execution methods, depending on expected return values and whether you want asynchronous operation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Keep the reply, because it's definitely of value for this task. In my case, I'll be doing other stuff as well, so it's more suited but +1 for the sample. You answer the actual question very well, anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server..."))
{
  SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandText = "insert into Records values (...)";
  connection.Open();
  int craeted = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Took liberty to change a bit in your reply. Nicely formulated, though +1.